# Displaying the actual value of the field in textbox

Tags: php, javascript, html

Im making an insert record code in php then i need to make a auto code, or the user just can look at the prepared value of the textbox, Ill just use this code.

```
$ayos = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select ib_code from item_brand order by ib_code desc limit 1"));
            $new_val = $ayos['ib_code'] + 1;
```

when you display it just use:

```
echo $ayos['ib_code'];
```

for example the output is **006**. the thing i cant resolve was when i try to display value of *$new_val* in the textbox, for sure our expected result if the $ayos['ib_code'] = 006 then the $new_val is equal to 007, but the problem is it is only 7 not 007, when displaying inside the textbox.. thx

[image: The screenshot of my problem thx guys!]

Comment: The above code displays what is there in your database so probably in your database its stored as 006 so it displays so.

Answer (score 1):

Try

if you want to display a number left-padded with zeros, consider using `printf()` (or one of its numerous relatives).

**Tested Example:**

```
<?php
    $a = '006';
    $b = $a + 1;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php printf("%03d", $b); ?>" />
```

Above code is tested.

[**sprintf()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) can do that:

```
echo sprintf('%03d', $ayos['ib_code']);
```

Or use `str_pad()` - but that's a little bit longer in code:

```
echo str_pad($ayos['ib_code'], 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Response to Some User Comment**

well if there are value like `0006` or `000006` then we can use above code is as below.

```
<?php
    $a = '000006';
    $b = $a + 1;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php printf("%0".strlen($a)."d", $b); ?>" />
```

what i am doing is passing `length dynamically` so if in future number `size increase` code will still work as expected.

Comment: may be we can pass string count dynamically there...let me test it.. then i will update it for u @user2051349

Comment: @user2051349 hey pal see my update its works too and tested with so many variety.

Answer (score 0):

Using the + operator forces PHP to interpret the variable as a number, which will truncate any leading zeroes. You'll have to do some interesting string manipulation most likely.

Answer (score 0):

The `006` ins converted to `number` and after that it adds `1` to it, It becomes `7` , When it becomes `number it truncates zeros` from left side.Use below code, it will pad `0` to left.

```
echo str_pad($ayos['ib_code'], 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); //becomes 007
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$realnumber = intval($new_val);`

`echo  $realnumber;`

Answer (score 0):

Assign `$new_val` variable like below:

```
//GET count of leading 0's into variable
$leading_zero_count = strspn($ayos['ib_code'], "0");    
$new_val = $ayos['ib_code']+1;
/** 
  * Pad the $new_val variable with 0's so that 
  * new length = total leading 0's + new length of $new_val
**/
$new_val = str_pad ($new_val, $leading_zero_count+strlen($new_val),0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```